# Is there any way to stop this page to directly jump on the other one?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to create a script in selenium using Java. But as soon as I run it, first, the desired page opens up but then automatically it is re-directed to that website's main page.
Here is the code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;  
public class second {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/chromedriver");  
     WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
     driver.navigate().to("https://www.testandquiz.com/selenium/testing.html");  
     String sampleText = driver.findElement(By.className("col-md-12")).getText();  
     System.out.println(sampleText);  
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("This is a link")).click();  
     driver.findElement(By.id("fname")).sendKeys("JavaTpoint");  
     driver.findElement(By.id("fname")).clear();  
     driver.findElement(By.id("idOfButton")).click();  
     driver.findElement(By.id("male")).click();  
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.Automation")).click();   
     Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("testingDropdown")));  
     dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Automation Testing");  
     driver.close();  
    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Provide the desired page's code.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen, what page is opened, at what point does a redirect happen, to where does it exactly redirect?

Comment: @Aniox This is the only code I am working on.

Comment: @luk2302 As soon as the form page is fully loaded it directly jumps to the link( driver.findElement(By.linkText("This is a link")).click(); ) which is attached without even clicking?